# TensorFlow: Difference between EVAL and INFER

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between `tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL` and `tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.INFER`?

Also, how exactly are these used with the `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` class object?

I am attempting to follow this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers, and I am struggling to understand the purpose of each of these "modes".

API documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/ModeKeys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that EVAL differs from INFER in that EVAL is the mode used when model is evaluated during training, where INFER is used when a model is already trained and is used purely to make predictions. For example, in the tutorial you linked, the loss function op is included in the graph when model is used in EVAL or TRAIN mode, but not in INFER mode. Because knowing the value of the loss function when doing training progress evaluation (EVAL mode) is useful, but when you are purely interested in generating predictions (INFER mode) you don't need it.

Comment: That is what I thought, however, most of tutorials that I have seen seem to separate training/evaluation into different modes (or even different scripts). This does not make sense to me, as it seems that the validation/evaluation step should be done iteratively within the training step, as a way to track progress during training, rather than evaluating performance after training. If this is the case, validating and testing would essentially be doing the same thing.

Comment: Well, the training and validation do different things and use different data, so in tensorflow graph they are separate ops. For example, if you are using dropout or dropconnect you might want to turn it off when doing evaluation or inference, but on when doing training.